# can you set .mouseZoomable(true) and .brush(true) for ordinal dc.js barChart?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I am trying add a zoom in and out and brush functions on a dc.js barChart ,but I could not get it to work.

Can you zoom or brush on an ordinal barChart?

Answer (score 1):

No, currently you can't zoom an ordinal chart. The discussion is here:

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/416

It isn't entirely clear what it would do, since ordinal scales don't have a continuous range like quantitative scales. I guess the best approach would be to treat it as a sorted list and quantize the zoom so that an exact number of bars are shown.